# Extra left join on same table in hibernate 6.x when using entityGraph and JPA specifications

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a query in the database in which I pass a specification with joins and an entity graph, which makes additional joins and I get a double left join

```
EntityGraph(
      type = EntityGraphType.LOAD,
      attributePaths = {
          "investorProfile",
          "investorProfile.investorProfileQuestionaries",
          "assetsRatio",
          "accountFees",
          "netAssetValues",
          "note",
          "clientAppropriateness"
      })
  Page<ClientView> findAllBySpecificationWithPage(Specification<ClientView> specification,
      Pageable pageable);
```

And get request in this format

```
select
        cv1_0.broker_id,
        cv1_0.client_id,
        af1_0.broker_id,
        af1_0.client_id,
        af1_0.id,
        af1_0.management_fee,
        af1_0.success_fee,
        cv1_0.accounts,
        cv1_0.agreements,
        ar2_0.broker_id,
        ar2_0.client_id,
        ar2_0.created,
        ar2_0.qtd_balance,
        ar2_0.qtd_twr,
        ar2_0.updated,
        ar2_0.ytd_balance,
        ar2_0.ytd_twr,
        cv1_0.broker_name,
        ca1_0.client_id,
        ca1_0.less_complex_appropriateness,
        ca1_0.less_complex_signed,
        ca1_0.more_complex_appropriateness,
        ca1_0.more_complex_signed,
        cv1_0.countries,
        cv1_0.current_var,
        ip1_0.id,
        ipq1_0.client_id,
        ipq1_0.id,
        ipq1_0.cache_updated_at,
        ipq1_0.filling_date_time,
        ipq1_0.investment_advice_agreement,
        ipq1_0.investor_profile,
        ipq1_0.is_actual,
        ipq1_0.is_cached,
        ipq1_0.is_confirmed,
        ipq1_0.template_id,
        ip1_0.updated,
        cv1_0.last_call_date,
        cv1_0.last_recommendation_date,
        cv1_0.name_en,
        cv1_0.name_ru,
        nav1_0.broker_id,
        nav1_0.client_id,
        nav1_0.id,
        nav1_0.account,
        nav1_0.currency,
        nav1_0.type,
        nav1_0.value,
        nav1_0.version,
        n1_0.broker_id,
        n1_0.client_id,
        n1_0.comment,
        n1_0.created,
        n1_0.last_contact,
        n1_0.tags,
        n1_0.updated,
        n1_0.updated_by,
        cv1_0.source,
        cv1_0.target_var,
        cv1_0.testing_results,
        cv1_0.type 
    from
        clients_view.client_view cv1_0 
    left join
        clients_view.assets_ratio ar1_0 
            on ar1_0.broker_id=cv1_0.broker_id 
            and ar1_0.client_id=cv1_0.client_id 
    left join
        clients_view.account_fee af1_0 
            on cv1_0.broker_id=af1_0.broker_id 
            and cv1_0.client_id=af1_0.client_id 
    left join
        clients_view.assets_ratio ar2_0 
            on ar2_0.broker_id=cv1_0.broker_id 
            and ar2_0.client_id=cv1_0.client_id 
    left join
        clients_view.client_appropriateness ca1_0 
            on ca1_0.client_id=cv1_0.client_appropriateness_client_id 
    left join
        clients_view.investor_profile ip1_0 
            on ip1_0.id=cv1_0.invest_profile_id 
    left join
        clients_view.investor_profile_questionary ipq1_0 
            on ip1_0.id=ipq1_0.client_id 
    left join
        clients_view.net_asset_value nav1_0 
            on cv1_0.broker_id=nav1_0.broker_id 
            and cv1_0.client_id=nav1_0.client_id 
    left join
        clients_view.note n1_0 
            on cv1_0.broker_id=n1_0.broker_id 
            and cv1_0.client_id=n1_0.client_id 
    where
        (
            cv1_0.broker_id, cv1_0.client_id
        ) in ((?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?)) 
    order by
        ar1_0.ytd_balance
```

AssetRatio makes join twice

```
left join
        clients_view.assets_ratio ar2_0 
            on ar2_0.broker_id=cv1_0.broker_id 
            and ar2_0.client_id=cv1_0.client_id`
```

```
left join
        clients_view.assets_ratio ar1_0 
            on ar1_0.broker_id=cv1_0.broker_id 
            and ar1_0.client_id=cv1_0.client_id
```

How to solve this problem and have only 1 join. the presence of an entity graph and specification is mandatory since I have custom queries, options with exsist are not suitable